# npm start command error for Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am stuck with problem for `npm start`. 
When I run the command `npm start` this error comes out.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! BuddyNest@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the BuddyNest@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the BuddyNest package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls BuddyNest
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bdstudiodesh\mango\mpatch\BuddyNest\npm-debug.log
```

I tried a lot but can't solve yet. Can anyone please help me regarding this issue. Thank you.

Comment: What is written in your `start` section in `package.json`?

Comment: is `./bin/www.js` your running file? What happens if you run node?

Comment: {
  "name": "untitled1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  }, is written there. Running this bin\www JavaScript file and when i run it shows: "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 10.0.4\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" bin\www
Tue, 17 Nov 2015 02:10:16 GMT untitled1:server Listening on port 3000

Comment: Did you figure this out @MohammadWahedulHaque